# How to dynamically create an event OnClick for a Groupbox?

Tags: delphi

I am new in Delphi and I am using the Altium PCB IDE not RAD Studio !!!
I created the form and added a Panel name : ListObject.
Then I created the button and added the OnClick event for this button.
When I clicked the button, It will create the groupbox inside the Panel 'ListObject'.
And I dont know how to Add the OnClick event to this groupbox.
The compiler show the error can not indentify the OnClick event.
Here is my code :

```
type

   TDynamicClick = class(TDynamicClick)

   public

      procedure ShowMessage(Sender: TObject);

   end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDynamicClick.ShowMessage(Sender: TObject);

begin

     TGroupbox(Sender).Caption := 'Clicked';

end;
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
     gb     : TGroupbox;
begin
       gb   := TGroupBox.Create(ListObject);
       gb.Parent := ListObject;
       gb.Height := 38;
       gb.align  := alTop;
       gb.OnClick:= ShowMessage;
end;
```

I dont know why !!!

Comment: In your form class, declare a member `procedure MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject)`. Then you can do `gb.OnClick := MyButtonClick`.

Comment: I just did it. But the Compiler still show the error : Can not indentify the OnClick event. I tried to put this code above the Button Click. But the compiler show the error : Can not access the top level variable !!

Comment: You didn't do it right. You need a declaration in the interface section (maybe in the form class's `private` section), and then the definition in the implementation section (with the class prefix).

Comment: Start by reading a book about Delphi programming, e.g. Object Pascal Handbook. You can download it on the Embacadero website in the Whitepapers section.

Comment: Please help me to write the code example. I did anything but The IDE still show the error : Undeclare identifier OnClick !!. I am using the Altium PCB IDE . It is not the RAD Studio. I dont know why !!
Here is the code : 
'''''''
type

TDynamicClick = class(TDynamicClick)

public

procedure ShowMessage(Sender: TObject);

//procedure imgSelectClick(Sender: TObject);

end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDynamicClick.ShowMessage(Sender: TObject);

begin

TGroupbox(Sender).Caption := 'Clicked';

end;
''''''''''
Error : Undeclare identifier ShowMessage !!!